# Elasticsearch Cluster issue on 7.7 using docker

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, elasticsearch-7

EC2 instance 1:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 \
        -e "bootstrap.memory_lock=true" \
        -e "node.name=es01" \
        -e "network.host=172.31.139.34" \
        -e "cluster.name=docker-cluster-test" \
        -e "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled=false" \
        -e "discovery.seed_hosts=172.31.135.140" \
        -e "cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02" \
        -e "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-XX:UseAVX=2 -Xms1g -Xmx1g" \
        --name=elasticsearch770 \
        --ulimit nofile=65535:65535 \
        --ulimit memlock=-1:-1 \
        docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.7.0
```

EC2 Intance 2:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 \
        -e "bootstrap.memory_lock=true" \
        -e "node.name=es02" \
        -e "network.host=172.31.135.140" \
        -e "cluster.name=docker-cluster-test" \
        -e "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled=false" \
        -e "discovery.seed_hosts=172.31.139.34" \
        -e "cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02" \
        -e "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-XX:UseAVX=2 -Xms1g -Xmx1g" \
        --name=elasticsearch770 \
        --ulimit nofile=65535:65535 \
        --ulimit memlock=-1:-1 \
        docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.7.0
```

I am getting issue

> BindTransportException[Failed to bind to 172.31.139.34:[9300-9400]];
> nested: BindException[Cannot assign requested address];

If I set don't set network.host=172.31.135.140, Its keep searching

Comment: Are you getting that error in the second instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed by adding --network=host in docker command on both EC2 instances

```
sudo docker run -d -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 \
        -e "bootstrap.memory_lock=true" \
        -e "node.name=es02" \
        -e "network.host=172.31.135.140" \
        -e "cluster.name=docker-cluster-test" \
        -e "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled=false" \
        -e "discovery.seed_hosts=172.31.139.34" \
        -e "cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02" \
        -e "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-XX:UseAVX=2 -Xms1g -Xmx1g" \
        --name=elasticsearch770 --network=host \
        --ulimit nofile=65535:65535 \
        --ulimit memlock=-1:-1 \
        docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.7.0
```